# can an old init.d and upstart script co exist together?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, upstart, init.d

I have an existing application that is deployed across many VMs. It uses init.d script to start the application. I want to switch to upstart. Do i need to delete the init.d script once i have upstart conf in place ? Or is it ok to have both at the same time ? Is it ok to call the init.d script from inside the script or exec block of upstart ?

Comment: I think you would be fine keeping it in `init.d`.  Upstart is only in CentOS 6 and it is no longer used in CentOS 7.  I had to use upstart to replace entries I had in `/etc/inittab` that spawned TTYs.  Why do you want to move to upstart??

Comment: @GoinOff: i want to use upstart to keep my application up all the time. In Upstart, you can configure it such a way that it the application crashes, it will start it again instantly